# Azure App Service restricting CPU utilitisation to 25%

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Has anyone come across an issue where Microsoft Azure App Service is restricting containers launched to 25% of the CPU utilisation? When the container is run locally it uses all of the CPU, but within Azure when trying to scale it is just using 25% and will not use any more, which prevents throughput.

Comment: As far as I know only if you are using Free trail there will be restriction in CPU usage, this could be a bug you can raise a request in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/) which will help you in resolving the issue.

Comment: Yes Microsoft are exploring the issue as it’s service effecting a large e-commerce site for a retailer, once I know the resolution I will post it

Answer (score 0):

Our issue with azure last week as been solved. There was an issue where if you were using multithreaded app services with custom docker containers, they would be limited to 1 core instead of the configured number. They released a patch globally over the weekend to fix it